# Numpy arrays instead of python lists - using nditer to create a 2d array from two 1d arrays

Tags: python, numpy

The following code works, but despite some effort can't figure out how to use numpy arrays (using nditer) rather than python lists (using enumerate).

It is for a psychology experiment where each trial presents one of four stimuli are presented and the participant's reaction time is recorded. Average reaction times are then calculated for each of the four trial types by creating an 2d array from the two 1d arrays.

```
trialTypeData = [3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3]
Rt = [900, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400]

RtByTrialType = [0, 0, 0, 0]
meanRtByTrialType = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for trialType in range(0, 4):
    RtByTrialType[trialType] = [Rt[i] for i, x in enumerate(trialTypeData) if x == trialType]
meanRtByTrialType[trialType] = sum(RtByTrialType[trialType])/len(RtByTrialType[trialType])

print "Average latencies by Trialtype:"
print (meanTrialTypeRt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `nditer`. There are better ways:

```
meanTrialTypeRt = [Rt[trialTypeData == trialType].mean()
                   for trialType in xrange(4)]
```

For each trial type, this selects the locations where `trialTypeData` is equal to `trialType`, gets those locations from `Rt`, and computes the mean. There are probably even better ways to do this with NumPy or SciPy statistical routines I'm unfamiliar with or don't remember at the moment; that list comprehension I'm using is a big red flag, and the runtime of this routine still grows unnecessarily with the number of trial types.

(Note that `Rt` and `trialTypeData` will need to be NumPy arrays for this to work.)

Comment: I think you can use members of the `bincount`/`digitize`/`histogram` trio to avoid the listcomp, but IMHO it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Excellent - this is exactly what I was looking for; both in terms of a solution and learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of data analysis, I'd recommend using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) instead of `numpy`; it makes a lot of things much easier.  In this case, you can do it using `groupby` (to collect items by type) and then `mean`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> trialTypeData = [3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3]
>>> Rt = [900, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Rt": Rt, "type": trialTypeData})
>>> df
     Rt  type
0   900     3
1  1200     0
2  1300     2
3  1400     1
4  1100     1
5  1200     0
6  1300     2
7  1400     3

[8 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df.groupby("type").mean()
        Rt
type      
0     1200
1     1250
2     1300
3     1150

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Better answer than mine!

Comment: This does indeed look very efficient, however I'm forced to use Numpy arrays because of the stimulus presentation package I'm using (PsychoPy). Thank you for introducing me to pandas though, I will have a read..

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
trialTypeData = np.array([3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3])
Rt = np.array([900, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400])

meanTrialTypeRt = np.bincount(trialTypeData, Rt) / np.bincount(trialTypeData)
```

Or if you know that there are the same number of instances for each trial type:

```
n_trials = 4
order = trialTypeData.argsort()
RtByTrialType = Rt[order].reshape((n_trials, -1))
meanTrialTypeRt = RtByTrialType.mean(1)
```

The second method might be slower (or not I haven't timed it), but it produces the `RtByTrialType` array which you can use if you need it later. The -1 in the reshape tells numpy to figure out what that value should be to make the reshape work.